# Firefox doesn't display any website with AppArmor enabled

Tags: 16.04, firefox, security, apparmor

I recently updated my Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Version 51.0.1 (64-bit). After the Update Firefox wouldn't show the content of any website - the screen remained blank. I did some digging and found out that AppArmor caused this and it turned out to be true. Doing

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

did the trick. Now my question:
For security concerns I want AppArmor to be enforced for Firefox. It has worked wonderful so far and it'd be great for it to be working in enforcing mode again. So how can I make the AppArmor profile operational without losing the ability to actually use the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with the apparmor profile I found on this page:

https://samiux.blogspot.it/2016/08/howto-hardening-and-tuning-ubuntu-1604.html

Hope it helps you as well.

Comment: You should include a brief summary of what you did that's in the link because over time some links will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research I found another solution to this problem on launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1627239

It appears that this is rendering issue. The workaround proposed in answer #3

```
echo "/dev/shm/org.chromium.* rw," | sudo tee -a /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.firefox
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

solved the problem for me as Firefox now renders websites with its AppArmor profile being enforced.